# über die Verben „talentieren“ und „proportionieren“

Tags: meaning, verb

Nachdem ich heute die zwei Adjektiven „talentiert“ und „proportioniert“ gehört hatte, dachte ich über diese zwei nach. Sie sind Adjektive, aber sehen wie Partizipien aus, und dann die Frage: von welchen Verben?

Ich habe für „proportioniert“ [dieses Verb](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/proportionieren) gefunden und ich hoffe, dass „proportioniert“ von jenem Verb stammt, aber nichts in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/talentiert) oder [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/talentiert?lookup=caseSensitive) für „talentiert“. Trotzdem gab ich nicht auf, ich war nicht genug davon überzeugt, deshalb fing ich an zu googeln, weil ich dachte, dass es ein zu „talentiert“ gehöriges Verb geben müsse.

Was ich gefunden habe, hat mich überrascht, auch auf Italienisch ([CLIC](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/sui-verbi-con-esempi-talentare-e-attalentare)), nämlich vielleicht existiert auf Deutsch ein [Verb](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=de&q=talentieren), aus dem „talentiert“ stammen könnte. Leider kann ich auch hier nicht sicher sein, weil ich nicht lese oder nicht lesen kann, dass „talentiert“ Partizip von „talentieren“ ist, und aus diesem Grund bitte ich jemanden um Hilfe und um Bestätigung (auch für das Verb „proportionieren“), und ich hoffe, dass er mir eventuell sagen kann, mit was für einem Verb wir es zu tun haben, ob „talentieren“ transitiv oder nicht ist, und was dieses Verb bedeutet.

Ich habe versucht eine Verbindung mit dem italienischen Verb „(at)talentare“ zu suchen und [diese Seite](https://books.google.de/books?id=099iAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=attalentare%20i%20cuori%20di%20se%20medesimo&source=bl&ots=U2Wk_XjnFy&sig=EZLwZqrR0ArJhxIxQkpZ2CCzQHM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ-ZKQqdLTAhWF6RQKHfSBA4sQ6AEIZjAJ#v=snippet&q=attalentare&f=false) und [diese andere Seite](https://books.google.de/books?id=BIkpzyQuGPkC&pg=PA340&dq=attalentare&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfreW35dLTAhXKaRQKHTDFD6IQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=attalentare&f=false) gefunden, auf denen ich die Verben „behagen“ und „gefallen“ und „reizen“ lese, sind die Bedeutungen dieser drei Verben die eventuelle Bedeutung des Verbs „talentieren“?

Comment: Mir gefällt Ihre Frage sehr gut! Was genau meinen Sie mit: „auch auf italienisch (CLIC), nämlich existiert vielleicht auf Deutsch ein Verb, aus dem „talentiert“ stammen könnte“?

Answer (score 8):

Das Adjektiv *talentiert* stammt vom Nomen *Talent* ab. Dabei gibt es dazwischen jedoch noch als Zwischenschritt das fiktive Verb *talentieren*, abgeleitet durch Anhängen des Suffixes *-ier*.
Auf canoonet findet sich eine Wortbildungsanalyse für *[talentiert](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/talentiert:A)*.

[image]

Ein direkt von Nomen abgeleitetes Adjektiv lautet *[talentvoll](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT00694#XGT00694)*, als Gegenteil von *talentlos*.

*Talentiert* gibt es auch erst seit etwa 1880 und hat *talentvoll* und *talentlos* Mitte der 90er in Häufigkeit überholt. Zumindest was das Geschriebene angeht.

[image]

*[Proportioniert](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/proportioniert:A)* ist vom 'echten' Verb *proportionieren* abgeleitet, welches mit dem Suffix *-ier* vom Nomen *Proportion* abstammt.

Das Suffix *[-ier](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/Suffixe-F/ier.html?country=D)*, was hier jeweils Verwendung findet, gilt als eines der am häufigsten vorkommenden Suffixe, um Nomen zu Verben abzuleiten. Es ist ein Fremdsuffix. *Talent* und *Proportion* sind lateinischer Abstammung. Daher ist es nicht verwunderlich, dass für das fiktive Verb *talentieren* das Suffix *-ier* verwendet wurde.

Comment: sehr interessant! Ein "fiktives Verb", ich verstehe! Aber, wenn ich z.B. hier https://books.google.de/books?id=trRKCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&dq=talentieren&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwz5DyztTTAhWCuBQKHZXnAZ0Q6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=talentieren&f=false oder hier https://books.google.de/books?id=0MMzAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=talentieren&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwz5DyztTTAhWCuBQKHZXnAZ0Q6AEISzAH#v=onepage&q=talentieren&f=false  lese, wie kann ich verstehen, was dieses Verb bedeut?

Comment: Ich danke dir sehr, ich kannte http://woerterbuchnetz.de/ nicht, außerdem in Rheinischen Wörterbuch habe ich folgendes gefunden: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=RhWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=RT00294#XRT00299, aber kann ich nicht verstehen und weiß nicht genau, was dieses Rheinische Wörterbuch ist. Ist es wie ein archaischer Duden?

Comment: @mle Die Ableitung zu "talentieren" kann jeder Muttersprachler einfach nachvollziehen. Wenn im Kontext sinnvoll, wird das Verb verstanden, auch wenn es eigentlich nicht gebräuchlich ist. Aber ich habe auch meine Schwierigkeiten, die Texte zu verstehen. Im ersten Link ist es auch widersprüchlich. Dort steht quasi: "Sie ist begabt, sie ist nicht begabt."
Den Eintrag im Rheinischen Wörterbuch kann ich auch nicht ganz nachvollziehen. Das ist auf jeden Fall ein Wörterbuch, das einen Dialekt  betrifft. Wörter, die dort vorkommen, werden nur in bestimmten Regionen verstanden.

Comment: Habe jetzt den ersten Text mal im ganzen Kontext gelesen. Die Frau stammelt da vor sich hin, weil sie den Liedtext vergessen hat. Warum sie da ein Wort verwendet, was es quasi eigentlich nicht gibt, bleibt mir ein Rätsel. Aber es hätte heißen sollen (das wird weiter unten klar) "sehr bekannt und sehr talentiert".

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt kein Verb "talentieren" - nicht in dem Sinne, daß irgendjemand einen normalen S-V-O-Satz damit bilden würde. Es gibt lediglich das Adjektiv "talentiert", das sich verhält *als ob* es von einem solchen Verb abstammen würde. Wenn ein Deutscher dies Adjektiv lernt, dann erschließt er die Bedeutung aus dem Nomen "Talent".

Es ist nicht ungewöhnlich, daß Vokabeln nur in ganz bestimmten Formen existieren. Das Englische "talented" zeigt dasselbe Verhalten, und das deutsche "proportioniert" fast dasselbe (ich kann mir einen Satz denken, der es im Aktiv verwendet, aber er erscheint nicht sehr natürlich).

Answer (score 3):

Dem [Etymologischen Wörterbuch von Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/talentiert#et-1) entnehme ich, dass das Substantiv *Talent* zuerst ins Deutsche gelangt ist und *talentiert* dann deutlich später direkt von diesem abgeleitet wurde. Ein zugehöriges Verb gibt es im Deutschen nicht.

Bei *proportioniert* ist die Situation für mich weniger klar. Auch hier kann das Adjektiv direkt aus dem Substantiv abgeleitet worden sein, es gibt aber auch das Verb [*proportionieren*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/proportionieren), dass der Duden jedoch als veraltet angibt. Ob dieses Verb jemals gebräuchlich genug war, um zu sagen, dass *proportioniert* ursprünglich ein Partizip dazu ist, weiß ich nicht.